# Comparison and coloration of 2 Sheets via Macro

Tags: vba, excel

Hello stackoverflow community,

in advance, im very new to VBA and Excel Macros so pardon me for not understanding some stuff. 
I have 2 sheets in Excel 2010 with 1 Table each.

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LRZq.png)

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8YRH.png)

Some rows are equal some not.

While testing some different codes, this one:

```
With ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("L1048576").End(xlDown))
    Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Managed to delete the duplicates on one sheet.

What I need it to do is:

Color the duplicates red and the uniques green, instead of deleting them.
Aditionally I need to compare the sheets with each other instead of doing it on one sheet.

I hope the question is understandable.

EDIT:

Thats what I've got so far:

```
Sub duplicateTest()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets(2)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(3)

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown)
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown)

        If Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Value = "" Then

        Else

    rng2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 7658646 '                           <~~     The color for uniques

        End If

    For Each cell1 In rng1
        For Each cell2 In rng2
            If cell1.Value <> "" And cell2.Value <> "" Then
                If cell1.Value = cell2.Value And cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                    cell2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255 '              <~~  The color for duplicates
                    End If
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell1
End Sub
```

Changed it to this because it shall do it to the end of the column.

```
Set rng1 = ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown)
```

This one so it doesn't color the blank cells green

```
If Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Value = "" Then

Else
```

To color the entire row instead of 1 cell

```
rng2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 7658646
cell2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255
```

The problem I have now is that it's not coloring anything. That said it's not giving me an error message either so I guess it's kind of working codewise? I can't find a mistake in the code which could cause this so I guess it has to be something else.

Thanks in advance

Regards, Crossie

Comment: Finding duplicates can be done with conditional formatting - you don't need VBA for that (but it can be done with VBA as well, of course). What do you mean when you say "compare the sheets"? Compare what columns, looking for what, doing what with the results?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I want to compare the columns A + B with A + B from the second sheet. That said, the other columns are supposed to be connected to them. I'm looking for duplicates and uniques. The result shall just show if there are duplicates and if so, where they are.

Comment: So you want to compare col A & B from sheet 1 with col A & B from sheet 2, and check if there are any duplicates -- meaning that any entry that is on both sheets qualifies as a duplicate? And it would be sufficient to add a background color to the entries that are duplicate?

Comment: My mistake again. The entry qualified as a  duplicate is supposed to be on the 2nd sheet as well as the color. The 1st sheet is not supposed to be colored. EDIT: Yes it is sufficient.

Comment: See my updated answer. Edit: actually, hold on. I have to fix something else. The cell comparisons are off, because I assumed the columns were next to each other. Give me one minute.

Comment: Come to think of it, my assumptions may be wrong altogether. Which columns are supposed to be a part of the evaluation? The ranges you tried to set in the code makes no sense to me - you can't compare sheet 1 col B with sheet 2 col D - they will never have the same value. Did you mean that you want to compare col B and col D in both sheets? I have updated the code under the assumption "compare columns B and D in sheet 1 with columns B and D in sheet 2".

Comment: Alright, I don't even know myself why I used "D" yesterday... The used columns are B, C and L. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, but does that also mean for all 3 columns to be evaluated? And if so, I assume the values in these columns *all* have to match between the sheets in order to qualify as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes. They're all connected in the row. (Column A to X) Only the 3 of them (B, C, L) are unique inside the first sheet. That said in sheet 2 I ONLY have these 3 values, instead of all from A to X.

Comment: In sheet 2, are these values still in columns B, C and L?

Comment: Yes I made sure. It's B, C and L on both sheets. Re: to your other comment. I've tried changing the offset to (0,12) since, if I understood correctly, this tells Excel how many columns to consider. EDIT: It didn't work. I think that might be because of the 9 blank cells in between.

Comment: The offset from col B to col L is 10, so that's probably why. Try: `If cell1.Value = cell2.Value And cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value And cell1.Offset(0, 10).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 10).Value Then`

Comment: The `Offset` function always works relative to some parent range. If I say `Range("C1").Offset(0,1)`, this can be said in English as "starting in the cell `C1`, move zero steps in the ROW direction and move ONE step in the column direction". Positive values move down for rows and to the right for columns. So the resulting position would be `D1`.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you so much. Now, would it be possible to not have it color further than "L"?

Comment: Yes. Replace `rng2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 7658646` with `Range(rng2, rng2.Offset(10)).Interior.Color = 7658646`

Comment: Green is limited now. Red still ongoing. Can't come up with anything to fix red.

Comment: You have to do the same there. Change `cell2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255` to `Range(cell2, cell2.Offset(0,10)).Interior.Color = 255`

Comment: Ohh I was pretty close then. Had `cell2.offset(0,10).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255` I've finished this now thanks to your great help. Thank you so much and keep up the good work! Regards, Crossie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to take care of the range declarations to suit your workbook. It's possible to do something dynamic if that's required, but there are varying solutions depending on how your data looks.

The colors can be modified as well, of course. I've marked where the codes are located.

```
Sub duplicateTest()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets(2)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(3)

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A1:A100")
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1:A100")

    rng2.Interior.Color = 7658646 '              <~~ The color for uniques
    rng2.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = 7658646 ' <~~

    For Each cell1 In rng1
        For Each cell2 In rng2
            If cell1.Value <> "" And cell2.Value <> "" Then
                If cell1.Value = cell2.Value And cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                    cell2.Interior.Color = 255 '              <~~  The color for duplicates
                    cell2.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = 255 ' <~~
                End If
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell1
End Sub
```

In response to your edit:

```
    If Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Value = "" Then
    Else
rng2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 7658646
    End If
```

This won't color anything, because you are saying to the compiler:

> If the bottom-most cell in the sheet is empty, do nothing. If it's non-empty, color it with this value.

We can prove this by asking the compiler what address it looks at when it evaluates the expression you supplied:

```
? Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Address
$D$1048576
```

We can see that this results in a single cell, its location being in column D, row 1048576.

Here is my suggestion, see if this works better:

(**Do note:** at the top of the code, you have to change the `Worksheet` references so it matches the sheets you are using in your workbook. I have used numerical values, meaning "sheet number 1 and sheet number 2. You can also use the actual sheet names, like this: `Worksheets("Sheet 1")`)

```
Sub duplicateTest()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(2)

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)

    ' Let's color the entire used range. We'll fix the colors later.
    Range(rng2, rng2.Offset(10)).Interior.Color = 7658646 ' <~~ The color for uniques

    For Each cell1 In rng1
        For Each cell2 In rng2
            If cell1.Value <> "" And cell2.Value <> "" Then
                ' If the cells are duplicate, color them
                If cell1.Value = cell2.Value And cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value And cell1.Offset(0, 10).Value = cell2.Offset(0, 10).Value Then
                    Range(cell2, cell2.Offset(0,10)).Interior.Color = 255 ' <~~ The color for duplicates
                End If
            ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then
                ' If the cell in sheet 2 is empty, remove the coloring
                cell2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = xlNone
            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell1
End Sub
```

Comment: This is helping a  lot. I'll get more specific in case adapting it to my table gets problematic. Thanks!

Comment: Stated some more problems.

Comment: Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" in
        `Set rng1 = ws1.Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`

Comment: Try the revised code for the range declarations. They should work universally now.

Comment: Works, Thanks. That said it colors the duplicates and uniques green.

Comment: That's because it can't find any duplicates (due to wrong cell comparisons). Re: my other comment to your question, I have to know which columns you want to be included in the comparison.

Comment: Or you can change it yourself: change the `Offset(0, 2)` to whatever you need. The second number indicates what position the column has relative to the range you are offsetting from. Meaning, currently it says "look for rows where column B and column D are equal in sheet 1 and 2".